# ElementDoesNotExist in splinter

Tags: python, splinter

I am using splinter to buy my tickets on the website, and I use `Browser(chrome)`. The page I want to parse is  `https://kyfw.12306.cn/otn/leftTicket/init`, 
I want to click the `u"预定"` by splinter.

But when I run the code:

```
b.find_by_text(u"预定")[order-1].click()
```

It shows the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/liangxiaoyu/PycharmProjects/shiyanlou/qiangpiao.py", line 54, in <module>
    getTicket()
  File "/Users/liangxiaoyu/PycharmProjects/shiyanlou/qiangpiao.py", line 44, in getTicket
    b.find_by_text(u"预定")[0].click()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/splinter/element_list.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    self.find_by, self.query))
splinter.exceptions.ElementDoesNotExist
```

I am really sure that the page contain the text `"预定"`, so what can I do?

Comment: which site are you testing?

Comment: I am using the 12306 website to test,and I met the problem~~~

Comment: Which site are you testing would be helpful to answer your question, please [edit] your question and add that into your question (remember add the full url).

Comment: thank you very much ,i have changed just now ~~~mua~

Comment: Well, since I don't know anything about splinter...but can't you search the button by class name? The `预订` buttons class name are `btn72`.

Comment: By the way, looks like selenium can do this, whatever use `driver.find_element_by_link_text('预订').click()` or `driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn74').click()`.

Comment: I change it,but I failed,that "WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_by_class'",but still thank you very much,en ,I will still try it after my exam ~~ ~~mua ~~

Answer (score 0):

You should pay attention that the `预订` button will appear only when you have logined in and search the specific train by giving the depart, destination and travel data. After login, you can try the following code.

```
from splinter import Browser

    browser = Browser('chrome')
    # Visit URL
    url = "https://kyfw.12306.cn/otn/leftTicket/init"
    browser.visit(url)
    # Find and click the '预订' button
    button = browser.find_by_text('预订')[order-1]
    # Interact with elements
    button.click()
```